# CSS HTML - DIV height fill remaining space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a layout like this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div id="col_1" style="float:left;width:150px;">1</div>
<div id="col_2" style="float:left;width:100px;">2</div>
<div id="col_3" style="float:left;width:<REMAINING_WIDTH>;">3</div>
```

col_1 and col_2 take up a fixed amount of space. I want the third column to take up the rest of it. What is the best way to do accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make all the answers.

Comment: Didn't you were just asking about height instead of width?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could do something crazy, abandon the javascript and the not-quite-ready-for-prime-time CSS3 stuff and use absolute positioning.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx7U7/).
Bonus points for behaving well through browser resizes, too.

```css
#col_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#col_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: #ccd;
}
#col_3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 250px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #cdc;
}
```

```html
<div id='col_1'>Column 1</div>
<div id='col_2'>Column 2</div>
<div id='col_3'>
  Column 3
</div>
```

Comment: Did you test your example. I do no see col3 filling out the remaining space. http://jsfiddle.net/Hb6rL/8/

Comment: JSFiddle updated.  Just had to add a 'right: 0px;' to column 3.

Comment: This is correct and should be the accepted answer.  Using JavaScript for basic layout is terrible form.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript is needed for this. If you want all 3 divs to fill up the window space (100%),  then you we need to use javascript to detect how much space is left and assign the height of col_3 accordingly. With jQuery you can do

```
var one = $('#col_1').height(),
two = $('#col_2').height(), 
remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height() - one - two); 
$('#col_3').height(remaining_height);
```

Comment: This worked, for the most part. Had to add some buffer space since the widths don't include padding/margin, etc.

Comment: If you wish to work it out with margin + padding, use .outerHeight();

Comment: There's a way to do it without javascript; see my answer below.

Comment: @FMM Your answer is not below anymore ;)

Answer (score 4):

You've already accepted an answer, but you could check out CSS Flexbox, which is designed to solve this exact problem without relying on "float:left" hacks.  It works on Chrome, Safari, and FF (with -webkit and -moz prefixes). Not on IE yet.

Here's some quick links:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

http://www.terrainformatica.com/w3/flex-layout/flex-layout.htm

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

Comment: Be careful with flexbox, [it probably doesn't work the way you think it does](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Jan/0186.html), there's a [new draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/Overview.new.html) which changes the way they work to be more intuitive.

Comment: Not that I'm condemning your suggestion, but isn't describing floats as "hacks" a bit much? Especially given flexboxes (unfortunate) lack of support.

Comment: These days **Flexbox** is the way to go unless you have to support really old browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You need a block formatting context:

```
#c1,#c2 {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#c2 {
    background-color: green;
}
#c3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

it is the overflow that makes it work. More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 2):

Here is somthing i thought about using some CSS only. i've tested it in FF12, GC18, SAF5.1 & IE 7,8,9,9CV.

```css
.Clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.Clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] .Clearfix {
  display: block;
}
* html .Clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}
#Wrapper {
  background-color: #FC20C9;
}
#col_1 {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#col_2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #00CC00;
}
#col_3 {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  background-color: #0066FF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper" class="Clearfix">
  <div id="col_1">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div id="col_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  <div id="col_3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Either using jQuery to calculate the remaining space, or use the css3 flexible box to fill up the remaining space:

http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

diagram2 is the case you want - the last box with maximum 'box-flex' will take the remaining space (default box-flex is 0)

Answer (score 0):

If you target the most recent browsers you can use the HTML5 `calc` function

```css
#col_3 {
  width: calc(100%-(100px+150px));
}
#red {
  border: 1px solid goldenrod;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
  <div id="col_1" style="width:150px; float:left;">1</div>
  <div id="col_2" style="width:100px; float:left;">2</div>
  <div id="col_3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

take off the width, and it should expand to fill everything. put width:100% if you'd like. you should check out the firebug plugin for firefox.

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox (the div goes to the next line). How can firebug help me with this issue?

Comment: that won't work. the 100% will only make it take the width of the parent element, obviously that's not what was intended.

Answer (score -1):

Put all three div's in a container, give col 1 and 2 fixed widths and set the 3rd to auto.