# Limit Child DIV Height to Parent DIV Height With Variable Sibling

Tags: css, height, percentage

I have a container `<div>` with a specified height, and contained within are two more DIVs, on for introductory copy that will vary (entered by the client), and another to list out various features.

I want the features `<div>` to automatically fill the remaining space in the parent, and then scroll out the overflow.

How do I do that?

**CSS:**

```css
#article {
    width:940px;
    height:500px
}

#article-content {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#article-features {
    height:100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tylonius/Dw9EZ/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way to do it with HTML4 other than relying on javascript to dynamically change the height of the bottom div based upon calculation (parent_height - sibling_height).

You may look at this: [CSS HTML - DIV height fill remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059021/css-html-div-height-fill-remaining-space)

With HTML5 you may use Flexbox to use the remaining space. Note that there are some limitations but it can answer your requirements. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.